# Can't change Google Chrome icon

Tags: icon

For every other application package I've looked at, there's a Paste option available in Edit menu after selecting the icon in "Get Info" dialog. For Google Chrome, there isn't.

[image: Google Chrome Info]

Why is that (i.e. is Chrome blocking the change somehow)? How can I get around this and change the icon? I'm sure there are apps for handling this, is there a way to do it without one?

Comment: Because of how Chrome updates, you will have to do this over and over again. Each time it pushes an update to you, it overwrites the old icon too.

Comment: Select the icon instead, and you will be able to paste. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169721/files-image-well-displays-png-icon-not-actual-png for instructions. @jmlumpkin The benefit of this method is that Google Chrome will not overwrite this setting because Google Chrome only modifies the binary and framework, not the top `Contents/` folder this icon is stored in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the package, "show package content", then go in the "ressources" folder and change the icon there. The icon file is the `.icns` file.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be please more specific on how and what to change? I've figured it out, but your answer seems incomplete this way.

Comment: Like that or more ?

Comment: By the way, I had to remove Chrome from Dock and put it back there to make the new icon appear in Dock (finder showed new icon right after I've changed the icns file).

Comment: More, I guess, mention what icns files are there, how to edit them perhaps?

Comment: @Martin you will always have to do that anyway, or in the terminal type: "killall Dock" to restart the Dock, because it keeps a cached copy of the icon.

Comment: @Martín I see! `killall` is easier than replacing the app in dock, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- "Show Package Contents", Contents, Resources
- Replace app.icns with a new icon set
- Go to a Terminal and do `touch /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/` and `killall Dock`

Voilà