# File's image well displays PNG icon not actual PNG

Tags: macos, finder, icon

I would like to replace the standard icon for an Automator application that I created with a PNG.  Unfortunately, the resulting icon is the generic PNG icon, not the *actual* PNG image.

Steps:

- downloaded the desired [image (512 x 512)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GraphvizLogo.png)
- verified that the image had a transparent background
- Opened the file's inspector window (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>):

[image]

- Dragged the PNG to the image well:

[image]

The final result:

[image]

Is there a way to get the actual icon to be used?

Comment: Have you tried copy-pasting the image? I.e.: open .png in Preview,select all, copy, open inspector on automator app, click on icon and press cmd+v.

Comment: OK, that worked.  Why?  What's difference between the two approaches?

Comment: Is your Finder configured to show the icon or the preview of an image file? If it's set to show the icon, then this might be the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy paste the `.png` image onto the icon shown in the Inspector.

1. Open the `.png` with Preview
2. Select all with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. Copy with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
4. Select the application of which you want to change the icon.
5. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open the Inspector
6. Click on the icon and paste the copied image using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

I have no clue why that works differently compared to dragging and dropping the image.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the above worked for me, but only after I was still having some puzzling difficulties, so if that's you, on your desktop (make sure you are clicked on your desktop) go up to the top, to Finder - View - Show View Options

... and use the little slider to adjust the size of your icons, slide it back and forth, even back to where it started and I found for me that for some strange reason my icon just popped up. (I was trying to get a new transparent icon the image for a Hard Drive and all I was getting was a standard PNG graphic but when I used the slider, it changed to my new icon. Go figure.)